# How do I find the numbers that are not listed or missing?

Tags: python, bash

I'll have a list of numbers, each on its own line (say 0 -100).  How do I find the numbers that are not listed or missing?

Comment: Do you have repeated numbers? Are they sorted? Is this homework? :-)

Answer (score 12):

Add them all to a set. Then subtract from a set filled with 1-100. Here's an example for 0-9:

```
>>> set(range(10)) - set([1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 2])
set([0, 9, 3, 7])
>>>
```

I had `[1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 2]` listed. To find out which numbers in range 0-9 are missing, I created a set with all of 0-9 and then subtracted the set with `[1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 2]` from it. And found out that `[0, 9, 3, 7]` were missing.

Sets are fairly efficient for this. As an added benefit, duplicates will be handled gracefully.

Comment: That's a really beautiful solution.

Comment: No repeated numbers and yes they'll be sorted.  No this is not homework :)

Comment: If you need the output sorted just dump the set into a sorted list

Comment: @curious1 then this is probably the best answer you'll get, although sorting here is irrelevant.

Comment: @Eli, slightly off-topic. Would `xrange` instead of `range` in the set constructor be more efficient, or is this optimised out, say in python 2.7?

Comment: @juanchopanza: I suppose it could be a bit more efficient, since the set constructor takes an iterable. However, I wouldn't expect the difference to be felt unless the size is large (*certainly* not in 1-100)

Comment: I think 100 is close to parity on _this_ computer. ie, the overhead of xrange becomes equivalent to the time it takes to allocate and initialize 100 ints.

Answer (score 1):

If L is the list of numbers, then

```
set(L).difference(xrange(101))
```

saves creating a set from the xrange

```
In [1]: L=[1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 2]

In [2]: timeit set(range(101)) - set(L)
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.7 µs per loop

In [3]: timeit set(L).symmetric_difference(range(101))
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.2 µs per loop

In [4]: timeit set(L).difference(range(101))
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.73 µs per loop
```

Comment: You could use `difference` too, `symmetric_difference` is essentially a XOR

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `awk` solution using an associative (key-value) array:

```
printf '%s\n' 1 4 5 6 8 2 |
awk -F " " -v first=0 -v last=9 '
BEGIN { 
  for(i=first; i<=last; i++) 
    array[i] = 0
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    array[$i] += 1
}
END {
  for (num in array)
    if (array[num] == 0) print num
}
'
```

- First, we create an array with all numbers of a given range used as single keys with default value 0.
- Every input number then gets processed by awk as a key to the array so that the value gets incremented by 1.
- At the end, only those keys get printed that have not been incremented, i.e. that have a value of 0 (because they were missing in the input range of numbers).

Answer (score 0):

bash:

```
# first set up an array containing the whole range
declare -a nums
for i in {0..100}; do
  nums[$i]=1
done

# then read the file and remove the numbers from it
while read number; do
  unset nums[$number]
done < file.with.numbers

# the remaining array keys are the numbers not found in the file
for number in "${!nums[@]}"; do
  echo $number
done
```